# How to show the status of creating or updating a stack with Cloudformation using AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I'm trying to find a command that allows me to see the latest status of the creation/update of a Cloudformation stack.

I thought I could use `wait` preceding the command `stack-update-complete` (in this case for update) but nothing happens.

This is what I'm doing:

1. I execute the command to update my stack:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name my-stack \      
  --template-body file://my-stack.yml
```

2. Immediately after I run:

```
aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name my-stack
```

I want to see the latest status including the result (create, update, delete, and rollback) so I don't have to login into AWS console.

Thanks!

Comment: I used some 3rd party cli tool that basically wraps around the aws cli. Among other things, it automatically polls the status after kicking off an update. Unfortunately can't seem to remember the name of the tool now.

Comment: Thanks, @jingx
I found a few wrappers for cloudformation. Does any of these sound to you?
AWSie | AWS::CLIWrapper | Bash-my-AWS | NPM package cfn-create-or-update |  Alestic aws-cloudformation-stack-status 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's one of those listed under "CLI Tools" here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/awesome-cloudformation .

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try it. Thanks a lot!